# What are the consequences of upgrading my .NET analyzer's target framework to .NET 5.0?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I have been writing an analyzer and using .NET Standard 2.0 so that I could target .NET Framework 4.7.2, which I was using in the VSIX version of the analyzer. Soon however I chose to drop it as supporting it was not beneficial. Ever since I have wanted to upgrade the supported framework to .NET 5.0 to also get the new language features along the path.

How would that affect the end users that would include the analyzer to their projects through the released NuGet package? Should I also keep supporting the older framework versions?

Answer (score 5):

You can't use anything other than .NET Standard 2.0, because VS runs under .Net Framework 4.* and the `csc` Roslyn compiler runs under .Net 5/6. The common ground is .NET Standard 2.0, nothing else will work.

This is still the case with VS 2022, it is still a .Net Framework application, the only difference is that it's now a 64-bit process, which means that your analyzer needs to be `Any CPU` to work in both.

Comment: I've noticed there's some option about using .NET 5.0 analyzers in VS, won't those run during compilation of the project/solution? VS itself might not be capable of it, but the compiler process (`csc`) should emit any diagnostics produced by the analyzer since it's running in .NET 5.0/6.0.

Comment: Analyzers run during parsing when you open a file, type something or compile something in VS, so the analyzer needs to be loaded by VS itself. `csc` also separately runs them if you run it by hand, but VS doesn't use `csc` at all, it hooks directly into the Roslyn libraries and all linked analyzers.

Comment: Then that would explain why some analysis results are not shown in VS in real time until you compile the project, like warnings about nullity of a field at all times.

Comment: @Blindy Do you know why VS2022 is still run on the antiquated .NET Framework? I thought here we had a good reason to get rid of it once and for all.

Comment: I imagine it's because of the work required moving every single one of those thousands of dlls to .net5. I think they focused on making it 64-bit for 2022, and the next big release will be with the modern .Net.